# Finding the convolution kernel in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a two vectors of spatial data (each about 2000 elements in length). One is a convolved version of the other. I am trying to determine the kernel that would produce such a convolution. I know that I can do this by finding the inverse Fourier transform of the ratio of the Fourier transforms of the output and input vectors. Indeed, when I do this I get more or less the shape I was expecting. However, my kernel vector has the same dimensionality as the two input vectors when in reality the convolution was only using about one fifth (~300-400) of the points. The fact that I am getting the right shape but the wrong number of points makes me think that I am not using the ifft and fft functions quite correctly. It seems like if I were really doing the right thing this should happen naturally. At the moment I am simply doing;

```
FTInput = fft(in);
FtOutput = fft(out);
kernel = ifft(FtOutput./FTInput).
```

Is this correct and it's up to me to interpret the output vector correctly or have I oversimplified the task? I'm sure it's the latter, I'm just not sure where.

Thanks

Comment: You might ask on dsp.stackexchange.com. This is a system identification problem. There are two issues: the approach you take here models the system by an FIR filter of the same length as the data, which may or may not be a good model. And if your input and output signals are at all corrupted by noise, say by being digitized from analog transducers, the noise will tend to bias your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing things correctly, this is not a bug.

The problem of estimating a convolution filter given clean and convolved data is VERY HARD. Given "nice" data, you may get the right shape but retrieving the true support of the convolution filter (i.e. getting zeroes where they should be) is NOT going to happen naturally.

Comment: Thanks for that this is actually a little tangential to what I'm doing, more of a cross check. It seems like its probably the case that its never going to be as good as the measurement I'm trying to cross check.

Answer (score 2):

I think your ''problem'' comes from the inherent padding necessary for discrete convolution that your are neglecting

By dividing in fourier, you assume your convolution was made with a cyclic padding in the spatial (or that your convolution was made by multiplication in fourier, both are equivalent) but if your convolution was computed in the spatial domain, a zero padding was most likely used.

```
s=[1 2 3 4 5] //signal

f=[0 1 2 1 0] //filter

s0=s *conv0* f=[4 8 12 16 14] //convolution with zero padding in spatial domain, truncated to signal length
sc=s *convc* f=[9 8 12 16 15] //convolution with cyclic padding in spatial domain, truncated to signal length

S,S0,Sc, the ffts of s,s0,sc

approx0=ifft(S0./S)=[-0.08 1.12 2.72 -0.08 -0.08]

approxc=ifft(Sc./S)=[0 1 2 1 0]
```